# simple captcha error TypeError can't convert nil into Integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image, simplecaptcha

i am using rails 3.0.2 and ruby 2.0.0 with simple captcha gem.

Gemfile -

```
gem 'simple_captcha', :git => 'git://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha.git'
```

View -

```
Verification code:<%= show_simple_captcha :label => "Please type the verification code", :image_style => "simply_green", :object => "foo" %>
```

but **captcha image is not showing** in view.

Every time i am getting this error in rails console -

> Started GET
>   "/simple_captcha?code=d3423b2321c833f8974c50e34528603f111c0d40&time=1399313320"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-05 23:38:41 +0530
>
> TypeError (can't convert nil into Integer)

I also tried following this [blog](http://brijeshshah.com/simple-captcha-in-rails-3) but it did not work.

Controller:-

```
def contact
  if request.post?
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if @contact.valid_with_captcha?
       @contact.save_with_captcha
      flash[:title] = "Thank you"
    else
      flash[:title] = "Sorry"
    end
    redirect_to contact_us_path
  else
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your `Controller Code`  where you are `simple_captch`.

Comment: I already specified rails 3.0.2 and ruby 2.0.0, please read the Q.

Comment: Post your `image.rb` file of your `simple_catcha`